# Network error while downloading a file

Tags: html

I can't get my file download to work. I tried to reinstall xampp and recode everything to a really basic level. I just want to download a file through html.

Really basic code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>StartUp</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="get" action="files/Setup.exe">
        <button type="submit">Download!</button>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

But I still always get:

> Error - Network error

in chrome and:

> ....\Setup.exe.part could not be saved because the source file could not be read.

in firefox.

Comment: not good what you are doing, using **a** tag with download attribute

Comment: and be sure the url of the file is correct

Comment: But how should i do it then?

Comment: If you try to `curl` the resource from the command line does it work? I think it's an issue of `Setup.exe` not being at the path you specify. What's the URL you are accessing and what's the path you expect for `Setup.exe`. Perhaps try `/files/Setup.exe'?

Comment: If you are going to download a file, you better just wrap in a a tag ?